# Zappa — why does the certificate have to be stored in us-east-1 even when I'm not running in that region?

Tags: aws-lambda, zappa

Why does Zappa's certificate have to be in us-east-1 and not in the region where I'm running Zappa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate is for global CloudFront infrastructure, which resides not in a single region but in all regions. us-east-1 is AWS’ “main” region, and is where you need to create most stuff that’s used globally.